# A basic function for emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have never written an emacs function before and was wondering if anyone could help me get started. I would like to have a function that takes a highlighted region parses it (by ",") then evaluates each chunk with another function already built into emacs.

The highlighted code may look something like this: `x <- function(w=NULL,y=1,z=20){}` (r code), and I would like to scrape out `w=NULL`, `y=1`, and `z=20` then pass each one a function already included with emacs. Any suggestions on how to get started?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A lisp function is defined using [`defun`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/defun.html) (you *really* should read [the elisp intro](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/), it will save you a lot of time - "a pint of sweat saves a gallon of blood").

To turn a mere function into an [interactive command](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Interactive.html) (which can be called using <kbd>M-x</kbd> or bound to a key), you use [`interactive`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html).

To pass the region (selection) to the function, you use the `"r"` code:

```
(defun my-command (beg end)
  "Operate on each word in the region."
  (interactive "r")
  (mapc #'the-emacs-function-you-want-to-call-on-each-arg
        ;; split the string on any sequence of spaces and commas
        (split-string (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end) "[ ,]+")))
```

Now, copy the form above to the [`*scratch*` emacs buffer](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Interaction.html), place the point (cursor) on a function, say, [`mapc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mapping-Functions.html) or [`split-string`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Strings.html), then hit <kbd>C-h f RET</kbd> and you will see a [`*Help*` buffer](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Help.html) explaining what the function does.

You can evaluate the function definition by hitting <kbd>C-M-x</kbd> while the point is on it (don't forget to replace `the-emacs-function-you-want-to-call-on-each-arg` with something meaningful), and then test is by selecting `w=NULL,y=1,z=20` and hitting <kbd>M-x my-command RET</kbd>.

Incidentally, <kbd>C-h f my-command RET</kbd> will now show `Operate on each word in the region` in the `*Help*` buffer.

Comment: I believe the # is unnecessary. From the elisp manual, section 12.7. "The read syntax `#'' is a short-hand for using `function'.  The
following forms are all equivalent:

     (lambda (x) (* x x))
     (function (lambda (x) (* x x)))
     #'(lambda (x) (* x x))"

Comment: @seanmcl: `lambda` is a very special case. In ELisp (but not other Lisps!) at this time (but not necessarily in the future!) indeed `#'foo` and `'foo` are equivalent, but, when dealing with function calls, the former should be used.

Comment: Could you please explain why (for other lisps) the # should be used? Coming from an ML/Haskell background, it seems strange to treat a function differently from any other data.  Does it read a different cell when the # is omitted (function vs. variable)?

Comment: @sds, I think this is exactly what I want but it seems like it may be splitting at the comma but also leaving it in as part of the argument. Any thoughts on how to use them to split but them removing them? I'm using ess-eval-line-and-step as my function.

Comment: I do not observe this: `(split-string "a,b,  c" "[, ]+")` ==> ("a" "b" "c")`

Comment: @sds Strange, when I pass it to R it seems like the comma is still being passed. ``Error: unexpected ',' in "x=1,"``. I can reproduce your split-string comment above with no problem though.

Comment: what is your split call?

Comment: @sds ``(split-string (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end) "[ ,]+")))``, same as what you recommended. It seems like it may be an issue with the mapc since ``(mapc 'ess-eval-line-and-step (list "x=1" "y=2"))`` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: try edebug - it will let you step through the forms one by one. Also, I don't think `ess-eval-line-and-step` is the right function for programs.