# Why use #' before function arguments in emacs-lisp?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, common-lisp

I'm familiar with Emacs Lisp, but not Common (or any other) Lisp.  Some Lisp programmers suggest (e.g. [A basic function for emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076646/a-basic-function-for-emacs/17078405?noredirect=1#comment27008144_17078405)) that it's good to use `#'` in front of function arguments in Lisp code.  For example:

```
(mapc #'my-fun '(1 2 3))
```

In Emacs Lisp, I believe that this is equivalent to

```
(mapc 'my-fun '(1 2 3))
```

From the elisp manual, section 12.7.

> The read syntax `#'` is a short-hand for using `function`.  The
>   following forms are all equivalent:
>
> ```
>  (lambda (x) (* x x))
>  (function (lambda (x) (* x x)))
>  #'(lambda (x) (* x x))
> ```

and the help for `function`

> function is a special form in `eval.c`.
>
> ```
> (function ARG)
> ```
>
> Like `quote`, but preferred for objects which are functions. In byte
>   compilation, `function` causes its argument to be compiled. `quote`
>   cannot do that.

So it seems like a potential optimization, but no more.  Moreover, coming from an ML/Haskell background, it seems strange to treat a function differently from any other data.

### Question:

Do you agree that `#'` should be used in `emacs-lisp` function arguments?
(A brief explanation of why they're needed in Common Lisp would be great as well.)

### Notes:

I thought it may read a different cell when the `#'` is omitted (value vs function).  But
this seems wrong because the documentation for `function` doesn't say anything about grabbing the function cell.  This is achieved by using `symbol-function`.

Related questions are

- [The #' in common lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021965/the-in-common-lisp)
- [Writing lambda expressions in common lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213611/writing-lambda-expressions-in-common-lisp)
- [Why #' is used before lambda in Common Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325499/why-is-used-before-lambda-in-common-lisp/3325572#3325572)

but they seem to suggest that the `#'` is unnecessary, at least in lambdas.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should Emacs #'function syntax be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801396/when-should-emacs-function-syntax-be-used)

Comment: `EL` and `CL` are both [LISP2's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp#The_function_namespace). I.e. they have different namespaces for functions and variable. Not all LISPs are, eg. `Scheme` only has one and therefor doesn't need `funcall` at all. eg. `(let ((x (lambda (y) (+ y y)))) (x 5))`

Comment: Thank you for all the edits.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The quote character in `#'foo` has nothing to do with the one in `'foo`.

`#'foo` is replaced at *read time* by `(function foo)`.  When that is compiled and executed, it looks up the *functional definition* named by `foo` (by `defun`, `flet`, `labels` or similar).

`'foo` is replaced at *read time* by `(quote foo)`.  When that is compiled and executed, it is simply replaced by the symbol `foo`.

`Funcall` and `apply` (and thus generally higher order functions) take *function designators* as arguments.  A *function designator* can be a function or a symbol naming a function, so both `#'foo` and `'foo` are function designators.

Therefore, the forms `'foo` and `#'foo` seem interchangable at first glance.  However, the lookup of the real function is done at different times—`#'foo` is looked up where it is invoked, while the function named by `'foo` would only be looked up when it is finally applied.

If you use a function designator many times over, it is much more efficient to do the lookup just once, or even just at compile time.  That can be a really big timesaver, and translates to a smoother user experience in an editor.

Comment: Specifically in Emacs Lisp, I do actually think `'foo` and `#'foo` are equivalent, but using the latter is still a signal that you are after a function definition.

Comment: Do you want to use `#'function` for built in functions in bindings like `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c s") 'save-buffer)`? Or when calling an `fset` macro definition in a binding?